# determine viewing ray

Tags: geometry

Imagine looking at a photograph of a room.

This is a 2D perspective rendering of a 3D scene and I want to reconstruct the 3D scene.

[image]

Having identified two 2D rays - AB and BC in the my image - that are perpendicular on a plane, how can you determine the 3D ray between B and the camera?

Comment: What do you mean by 'determine the 3d ray between B and the camera'?

Comment: @copper.hat I mean compute the position of all points in 3D space.  Because we know that AB and BC are at right angles on something flat, we ought to be able to tell were the camera is relative to these points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem has been studied extensively by many people. There are various approaches to the seemingly magical process of reconstructing 3D information from a 2D image. The one you mention (assuming some part of the scene is orthogonal) is covered in papers by Antonio Criminisi. A good place to start is [this one](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/67279/criminisi_dagm2002.pdf). Or, even better, [this one](http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ee290t/sp13/readings/single-view-metrology-criminisi.pdf).

The field is called "single view metrology" by some people. That will give you some search terms to work with if the references above are not enough.